# Memory management with UINavigationController view

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

My application started out as viewbased but I had to change to navigation based later on. The way I did this was by creating a UINavigationController member in my `AppDelegate` and calling `pushViewController` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigator;

// didFinishLaunchingWithOptions implementation
MainController *mainView = [[MainController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainController" bundle:nil];
navigator = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[navigator pushViewController:newSongView animated:YES];
[mainView release];
```

In my `MainController view` I have a button that calls this method and sends the user to the next view:

```
- (IBAction)newViewLoader:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secVC animated:YES];
}
```

This works fine but the moment this button is pressed, the simulator starts using 5MB more of the memory. And when I press the `back` button on the navigation bar and than press the button that calls the `newViewLoader` method, 5MB more is taken by the simulator. And so on, every time the second view is loaded. So loading this view is quite expensive.

*Isn't there some way to unload the view when the back button is pressed, so that memory doesn't keep going up every time the view is opened?* Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMYX7.png) with what happens every time the view is loaded.

Comment: What about the nature of your view? It's quite normal to have memory consumption when you allocate a controller and its view. Obviously it depends on the elements allocated in that controller/view. For example an image could be expensive.

Comment: ditto Darren plus what is you 2nd view controller contain content wise, plus what does it do on load and appear?

Comment: What is ARC and how can I see if it's being used? As for my view, it mostly contains a large grid of buttons with custom images so I can understand that that could take space. But why is there a new instance of the view created each time? Can't I unload the view somehow, once the back button is pressed?

Comment: @Augie onLoad the view draws the button grid (with custom images) and sets some things inside a singleton-class

Comment: What tool are you using?  what specific stat are you looking at?  Are you sure your not looking at "Allocations" and forgetting about "Deallocations".  Meaning like it will allocate 5mb more ram but also release the past view freeing up the prior 5mb.  But also you should research ARC and at least know what it is.

Comment: @owengerig It is the allocations tool that I'm using and here's a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMYX7.png I'm trying to find where the deallocations are happening but can't seem to find it right away

Comment: @Flex_Addicted sorry. That was meant to go for Darren.

Comment: @Darren have you read the question at all? There's `[mainView release];` - how possibly could OP use ARC with that?

Comment: Ha, yes I read the question at all, but I forgot that calling release in ARC causes a build error. Good point though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using ARC then you have at least one memory leak in your IBAction. It should be:

```
- (IBAction)newViewLoader:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secVC animated:YES];
    [secVC release];
}
```

or what I prefer:

```
- (IBAction)newViewLoader:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secVC = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secVC animated:YES];
}
```

Otherwise you secVC is never  released. You could try adding the release and see what happens.

However you really should be using ARC, which is Automatic Reference Counting. This takes care of the releases for you. Read up on it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I actually thought I had tried `[secVC release];` and it was causing me some other problem but it seems to work fine, memory stays stable now. Thanks a lot!